# Using `$unwind` in MongoDB doubts of different `$sum` outputs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I´ve a doubt using `$unwind...`

First of all, this is my collection "Provincias.json" that stores info about Spanish regions (short example):

```
 {
  _id: ObjectId("62095151245a59e4bda99e9a"),
  Nombre: 'Soria',
  CA: 'Castilla y León',
  Superficie: 10306,
  Datos: [
   { Anyo: 2015, Valor: 91780 },
   { Anyo: 2014, Valor: 92630 },
   { Anyo: 2013, Valor: 93575 },
   { Anyo: 2012, Valor: 94463 },
   ..... ]
```

Where *CA* is the state name, *Nombre* the county name, *Superficie* county surface and *Datos* the population each year.

Well I´m trying to make a "query" that returns the info grouped by *CA* with total surface and the difference between max and min population densities.

My expression is as follows:

```
db.ProvinciasPEC1.aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$Datos"},
   {$group: {
       "_id": "$CA", 
       "totSuperficie": {$sum:"$Superficie"},
       "PoblacionMaxima": {$max: "$Datos.Valor"},
       "PoblacionMinima": {$min: "$Datos.Valor"}}}, 
        {$project: {
           "_id": 1,"totSuperficie": 1,
           "totPoblacion": 1,
           "diffDensidad": { 
               $divide: [ 
                 {$subtract: ["$PoblacionMaxima", "$PoblacionMinima"]} , "$totSuperficie"
               ] 
            }
         }
      },
      {$sort: {"diffDensidad":-1}},
      {$out:"CAM_Densidad"}
    ])
```

I returns me somethin like this:

[image]

But I don´t know why the total Surface is wrong.

Using the following expression I get States with proper total surface:

```
db.ProvinciasPEC1.aggregate([{$group: {"_id": "$CA", "totSuperficie": {$sum:"$Superficie"}}},{$out:"CAM_Densidad"}])
```

That returns:

[image]

Please, any hint to figure out what I´m doing wrong? I think is related to $unwind, but not sure,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's best to avoid including images of code/errors/text/etc. - just include them in a code block.

Comment: Can you tell what is the result you are looking for from the aggregation - explain each field in the expected output.

Comment: In this link you can see what I want: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PIvVqvBTjKe . I would like "totSuperficie" be the sum of fields "Superficie" of each json element. In my link I dont know why I dont get 93950 (correct answer).

In this example I get the correct answer https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uonv4jd94ik . So my question is why in first example is returning me back that sum(Superficie)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  Determine the min/max `Valor` per document, and then `$group` by `CA`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "maxV": {
        "$max": "$Datos.Valor"
      },
      "minV": {
        "$min": "$Datos.Valor"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "CA",
      "totMaxV": {
        "$max": "$maxV"
      },
      "totMinV": {
        "$min": "$minV"
      },
      "totSf": {
        "$sum": "$Superficie"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "diffDensidad": {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$totMaxV",
              "$totMinV"
            ]
          },
          "$totSf"
        ]
      },
      "CA": "$_id",
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CgmoamsUugF).

Comment: it works fine! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
   $unwind: "$Datos"
  },
  {
   $group: {
   "_id": "$CA",
   "totSuperficie": {
    $first: "$Superficie"
   },
   "PoblacionMaxima": {
    $max: "$Datos.Valor"
   },
   "PoblacionMinima": {
    $min: "$Datos.Valor"
   }
   }
  },
  {
   $project: {
    "_id": 1,
    "totSuperficie": 1,
    "totPoblacion": 1,
    "diffDensidad": {
      $divide: [
      {
        $subtract: [
          "$PoblacionMaxima",
          "$PoblacionMinima"
        ]
       },
      "$totSuperficie"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
     "diffDensidad": -1
   }
  },
  {
    $out: "CAM_Densidad"
  }
])
```

explained:

1. Unwind the Datos
2. Group the per CA (but preserve the Superficie since it is the same value for all unwinded Datos so if you sum them you will get different sum depending on number of Datos per CA )
3. Project
4. Sort by diff
5. Out to the output collection

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wqOi60UZwuf)

Comment: Hi there! first of all thanks for your answer, but I think I made a mistake explaining myself: what I would like to get is the sum(Superficie) as the sum of county surfaces to get the total state (CA) surface.

Here in this link I show you the entire json of a specific state ('Castilla y Leon') with all its counties: https://mongoplayground.net/p/l0biNUsBGDz . Total surface may be 93950...how would you get that? Thnks back again

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uonv4jd94ik Here you can see an example with correct sum(Superficie) if it helps you to figure out. Thnks!